# Minimal Flask app unreachable from Docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a very simple flask service that I'm trying to run inside a docker container.
I used python to implement a minimal application that is working fine on my Windows, but isn't reachable when inside a Docker container.
I tried the common fix of setting --host=0.0.0.0 (tried multiple ways), but it did not solve my problem.

**Project structure:**
├── application/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── service.py

**Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.6.5-alpine

RUN apk --update add bash nano

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV FLASK_ENV=development
CMD ["python", "service.py"]
```

**service.py:**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def greetings():
    return "Welcome my service!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Finally, here's the log when I start the Docker image in interactive mode:

```
[...]/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1"
 * Serving Flask app 'service' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 277-473-905
```

So there appears to be no problems, however when I use a browser (Google Chrome) to visit the address shown in the console, it just loads forever then displays that the site is unreachable (`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`).
Also, I can run the flask with no problem from my native OS by typing the following commands from a bash terminal:

```
export FLASK_APP=service
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

Can anybody help me understand why it's not working inside a Docker container? It's working from outside, and I thought adding `host='0.0.0.0'` was supposed to make the container accessible from outside.

Edit: docker command tested:

```
docker run --rm -it  scone:latest
docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 scone:latest
```

**RESOLVED**
The trick, as mentioned by u/OneCricketeer, is to use `-p 5000:5000` argument in docker run, and now you can use reach the container BUT you have to ignore the address given in the docker terminal. Use this instead : http://localhost:5000 (the ip it would give you if you ran flask from outside the docker container.)

Comment: Please show your Docker run command. Did you forget `-p 5000:5000`?

Comment: even with command:
```docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 scone:latest``` I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are likely seeing is that your windows host cannot get to the docker container.  The networking is not exposed to your host so you'll need to include the `-p 5000:5000` option on the docker command line to tell docker to forward host port 5000 to the docker container port 5000.

In short:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000  scone:latest
```

Comment: Full log using this command, I get the same results unfortunately:
```$ docker run --rm -p 5000:5000  scone:latest
 * Serving Flask app 'service' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 568-722-618```

Comment: OK that was the problem! I did not understand that once I mapped the port 5000 to 5000, I still had to use the locahost address from outside my Docker container and not the one it gives me in the console. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Tested with this Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.10-alpine

RUN ["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "flask"]

COPY service.py .

CMD ["python", "service.py"]
```

Run with

```
$ docker build -t tmp-flask .
$docker run --rm -e FLASK_ENV=development -p 5000:5000 tmp-flask
 * Serving Flask app 'service' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 248-506-880
```

From another terminal

```
$ curl localhost:5000
Welcome my service!
```

Comment: ```-p 5000:5000``` did the trick, thanks!